# Accessing embedded XML in javascript for chrome , works well in ie as document.XMLDocumet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsp, xslt

I am working on an old code which works on IE but now we are looking for a possibility to make it work on chrome. 
In our application JSP is used to fetch data from API in xml format. This XML is then sent to browse and it does href to xsl files.
We are using JS to access the XML and XSL and to transform it . 
The problem is in IE we are getting this xml with document.XMLDocument but this does not work in chrome. The document object looks different in chrome vs IE. Although i can see all the  xml ,xsl , JS files in the network with state 200 . But i am unable to access the xml file. Anyhelp  will be highly appreciated.
thanks

The code is very lengthy and i dont know what to put here..The picture is the response i am getting in network. The main has xsl ref and XML.Basically i want to access the XML in document which is main.But in my document i currently have the html content of XSL MainPage_CT.xsl file. Also the response coming here is from java code
session.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(getUrl(nextPage)).forward(request, response);
I know i am unable to give enough info. But can you interpret something from this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVWhm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MyTq.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some code examples to let us know more about the issue

Comment: there are minor xml api diffs between ie and ch/ff, show your code

Comment: Exposing `document.XMLDocument` is not supported in anything but old IE versions or current IE in backwards compatibility mode, other browsers have never supported that.

Comment: If you want to have a DOM representation of an XSLT or XML document with non IE browsers then use XMLHttpRequest to load them and access `responseXML`.

Comment: Hi Martin, Yes i understand this method. But my point is that we do ajax when we need data from server. In this case i already have the XML etc on the browser. Do you think it makes sense if do ajax for the same thing.

Comment: If you want a DOM representation then you need to get one. I so far have not understood why you need one as you seem to send the XML with a processing instruction `<?xml-stylesheet...?>` to the browser and the browser performs the XSLT transformation automatically without any need for scripting it with Javascript. But if you need the DOM representation of the XML document, then, with anything but IE, you need to use XMLHttpRequest and access `responseXML`. The browser will load and parse from the cache normally, so you won't have a second request over HTTP.

Comment: Hi Martin, Yes the browser in this case is doing the transformation and showing me the HTML. But it also has some JS function calls on load of the page. And there the XML is required. I want to know is there any other way possible without AJAX to get the XML.

Comment: As everything is working fine in IE , just to access this in chrome, will require so much things . As the IE is able to access it with XMLDocument , do we have any replacement of it in chrome.

Comment: As I said, if you want the DOM representation of the XML document in any browser other than IE, then you need to load and parse it with XMLHttpRequest, that `document.XMLDocument` property is not supported in other browser, not even in Edge I think, and not in IE 11 in standards mode.